# Material chip text is wrapped instead of expanding the chip

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material 8.2.3 and when I set the text in the chip text is wrapped and messed. What I want is the chip to be expanded to fill all text in one line

[image]

How is this possible? The code is:

```
<mat-form-field style="margin-left:20px" *ngIf="filterStatus">
    <mat-chip-list>
        <mat-chip color="warn" removable (removed)="removeFilter()" selected>
            Filter view on {{dateFrom | date:'yyyy:MM:dd'}}
            <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that the chip is too wide to fit in its holding container?

Check this example I made. It reproduces the problem you have: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p2hwr9

```
<h3>Chip list with container width set</h3>
<div style="width:150px">
  <mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip color="warn" removable (removed)="removeFilter()" selected>
      Filter view on {{dateFrom | date:'yyyy:MM:dd'}} - This is a sample view
      <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
</div>

<h3>Chip list without container width set</h3>
<mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip color="warn" removable (removed)="removeFilter()" selected>
        Filter view on {{dateFrom | date:'yyyy:MM:dd'}} - This is a sample view
        <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```